# How to decode OLAP Query?

Tags: sql-server, olap, olap-cube, servicemanager

I am totally fresher to OLAP server. i have a OLAP query that is working fine, i just want to know, which tables are linked to send the result and how(i mean with which joins). Here is query.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ThisYearMonthToDate] AS 'Sum({[Time].[All Time].[2013].
[Q1].[January],[Time].[All Time].[2013].[Q1].[February],[Time].[All Time].[2013].
[Q1].[March],[Time].[All Time].[2013].[Q2].[April],[Time].[All Time].[2013].[Q2].[May]}, 
[Measures].[Main Temp Id])'MEMBER [Measures].[LastYearMonthToDate] AS 
'Sum({[Time].[All Time].[2012].[Q1].[January],[Time].[All Time].[2012].[Q1].[February],
[Time].[All Time].[2012].[Q1].[March],[Time].[All Time].[2012].[Q2].[April],
[Time].[All Time].[2012].[Q2].[May]}, [Measures].[Main Temp Id])' SELECT {[Measures].
[LastYearMonthToDate], [Measures].[ThisYearMonthToDate]} ON COLUMNS,
{([PublicRegion].[All Regions].[USA]),([PublicRegion].[All Regions].[USA].[Northeast]),
([PublicRegion].[All Regions].[USA].[Midwest]),([PublicRegion].[All Regions].[USA].
[Southeast]),([PublicRegion].[All Regions].[USA].[Southwest]),([PublicRegion].[All 
Regions].[USA].[West Coast]),([PublicRegion].[All Regions].[USA].[Misc]),
([PublicRegion].[All Regions].[Europe]),([PublicRegion].[All Regions].[Europe].[UK]),
([PublicRegion].[All Regions].[Europe].[France]),([PublicRegion].[All Regions].
[Europe].[Italy]),([PublicRegion].[All Regions].[Europe].[Germany]),
([PublicRegion].[All Regions].[Europe].[Spain]),([PublicRegion].[All Regions].
[Canada]),([PublicRegion].[All Regions].[Other])} ON ROWS FROM Public
```

i am not getting how to decode this query. Please help me..

Comment: What OLAP tool you're using? What Database is attached as source to your cube?

Answer (score 0):

There are two pretty easy ways to find out:

1. Log of you OLAP server: I'm almost sure that all leading OLAP tools logs SQL queries sent to database server.
2. Log of your database server: Set your database to log all queries from all users. By time of execution, and user name you declared in metadata file, you can easily filter queries sent by OLAP tool.

Hope this helps,
Best regards